# how to fix no transaction is in progress in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

when I try persist some data that I recovered from my csv file on my database using my job processor in spring batch this error  appear in the console , for my dao i'm using hibernate

I already tried 2 methode but the same probleme !

first :

```
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(p);
```

second :

```
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(p);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

data source in my spring xml config : 
all my spring xml config here https://pastebin.com/RZPr1GKL

```
<bean name="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yassir" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>tp.entities.Personne</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

the error : 
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3450)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1418)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    ...

Comment: 1. Since you're using Hibernate, you should use a HibernateTransactionManager. 2. Since you're using annotation-based transactions, the bean method that is supposed to be transactional should be annotated with `@Transactional`. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-hibernate

Comment: I added the annotation @Transactional 
 public void savePersonne(Personne p) {
  Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
  session.saveOrUpdate(p);
 }
  but the problem is still there

Comment: Well, apparently you read the second part of my comment, but not the first one.

Comment: how to use a HibernateTransactionManager. ?

Comment: As shown in the link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: but i already have DataSourceTransactionManager ?

Comment: Which is helpful if you use JDBC to access your database. But you're using Hibernate.

Comment: You are using the wrong transaction manager, use the transaction manager that matches your persistence technology. In your case you should be using the `HibernateTransactionManager` (from the same package as your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`). That will make the first approach work (at least it should, if it doesn't you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we use spring batch especially for tasklet in spring boot project `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotations will create its own transactions (Spring Batch Transactions) for its default tables.
Hence if you want to perform any insert, update or delete in your application tables(acutal table performing `CRUD`). We have to explicitly mention `JpaTransactionManager` instead of default spring batch transactions.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
       
       @Autowired
       private DataSource dataSource;

       @Bean
       @Primary
       public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
            final JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
            tm.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return tm;
       }
}
```

**@Primary** is most important one to mention else two transaction managers will be loaded. Mention `jpaTransactionManager()` in your job.

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepOne")
                .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager())
                .<DetailDTO,DetailDTO>chunk(100)
                .reader(reportReader) 
                .processor(reportProcessor)
                .writer(reportWriter)
                .build();
```

Error which i got - `Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`.

Click Up Vote if this is useful for you.

Comment: still same problem javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3466) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]

Answer (score 4):

You configured Spring Batch to use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` to drive transactions. This transaction manager knows nothing about your Hibernate context. You need to use the `HibernateTransactionManager` to make the Hibernate `Session` in your writer participate in Spring Batch managed transactions.

I would also recommend to use the `HibernateItemWriter` instead of creating a custom writer (`PersonneWriter`) and manually creating the session and managing transactions.

A similar question/answer can be found here: [Spring Batch JpaItemWriter vs HibernateItemWriter and why HibernateTransactionManager is needed when HibernateItemWriter is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354066)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks when i'm using HibernateTransactionManager it work :  <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

Comment: so we just need to create bean, rest spring will take care? or do we need to specify it while running jobs

Comment: @user124 Creating a transaction manager bean is not enough. If you want to use a custom transaction manager, you need to provide a `BatchConfigurer` bean and override `getTransactionManager` to return your transaction manager, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig.

Comment: can u help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056392/how-to-add-hibernatetransaction-manager-to-spring-batch

Comment: but the link you mentioned in the answer, it provides transaction manager when configuring step      byt       .transactionManager(tManager), it is not overriding BatchConfigurer as you are saying?

Comment: @user124 which link are you referring to? As requested, I added a comment on your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056392/how-to-add-hibernatetransaction-manager-to-spring-batch so please reply on that question. It is not efficient to cross links like this because no one can be sure we are talking about the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if you are confused. I am referring to current question only. I will add queries related to other question on that thread only. What I am saying is the link you mentioned in the answer in this post only ": Spring Batch JpaItemWriter vs HibernateItemWriter and why HibernateTransactionManager is needed when HibernateItemWriter is used" . it is not using BatchConfigurer as you are saying?