# spring-repository save doesn't work when add spring-batch dependency?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

There is application on spring4+jpa deploied on websphere 8.5.5.13
There is JPA saving in database.
So, after I added spring-batch -I faced with problem, jpa entities doesn't save.

So, the reason in transaction manager configuration like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947970/transaction-management-with-spring-batch), if I add transaction manager - JPA try to use it too.

I have root config like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppInitalizer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(
                WebConfig.class,
                ServiceConfig.class,
                PersistenceConfig.class,
                BatchConfig.class
                );
                ....
    }
```

For just save entity I use spring-controller and spring repositoty. Code for saving is

```
record = new UserRecord(name, surname, age, updateDateTime, serialize(UserToSave));
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "UserRecord")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class UserRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "PR_KEY")
    private String prKey;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    //Business Key
    @Column(name = "age", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "updateDateTime", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private Timestamp updateDateTime;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "user", length = 100000)
    @Lob
    private byte[] user;

    public UserRecord(String name, String surname, String age, Timestamp updateDateTime, byte[] user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
        this.updateDateTime = updateDateTime;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Spring-repository:

```
  @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> 
     {}
```

When I added BatchConfig and some bean into, doesn't saving occours..

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job processJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("processJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Person, Person>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() {
        return new JobCompletionListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Person, Person> processor(){
        return new ItemProcessor<Person, Person>(){
            @Override
            public Person process(Person person) throws Exception {
                person.setName(person.getName().toUpperCase());
                person.setSurname(person.getSurname().toUpperCase());
                person.setAge(person.getAge());
                adminInfo.append("processing person" + person);
                return person;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("simple-data.csv"));
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {
            {
                //3 columns in each row
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "name", "surname", "age" });
                    }
                });
                //Set values in Employee class
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Person.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> writer(){
        ItemWriter<Person> writer = new ItemWriter<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends Person> messages) throws Exception {
                for (Person msg : messages) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Writing the data " + msg);
                }
            }
        };
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }
}
```

my pom.xml is:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>SomeNAme</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--SPRING-BATCH CONFIGURED-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
                                <!--JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
                           <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
                          <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                        <!-- SERVLET-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
                         <!--JACKSON AND XML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--APACHE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So, this is libraries issue? (I tried to comment all spring-batch code and leaves only depedency in pom - and it starts to work..

my beans related with database is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"persistence"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"persistence""})
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Resource(type = DataSource.class, lookup = "jdbc/MyDataBase", name = "jdbc/MyDataBase")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataBase");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        log.info("Entity Manager configured.");
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    //Set properties hibernate
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field", false);

        properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
        properties.put("useSSL", false);
        properties.put("requireSSL", false);
        properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
        properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
        properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I think that reason is in Transaction management, but can't to configure it correct way. If I use this way for creating transaction management:

```
 public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new WebSphereUowTransactionManager();
    }
```

or

```
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

I have an error message

> Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
>   JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?];
>   nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table
>   or view does not exist

this is because I have no temp table for spring batch..

If I used

```
 public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }
```

spring - batch work, but doesn't work saving jpa entities..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transaction management with Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947970/transaction-management-with-spring-batch)

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine this issue is related, and root cause in transaction management configurations. But can't configure transaction management for correct work

Answer (score 4):

Root cause is not in dependecy conflict. The reason is that there are 2 bean with same name for JPA and for spring-batch. So, creating bean with different name is solved a problem.

```
@Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager springBatchTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

 @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(ResourcelessTransactionManager springBatchTransactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(springBatchTransactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(springBatchTransactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

Comment: can you explain more on "having 2 beans with the same name" ???? I think I'm having the same issue - I upgraded my spring-batch-core from 1.x.x to 2.x.x and my spring data JPA isn't saving to Database anymore! help!